# Find the exact length of the curve $y=\frac 12 x^2- \frac 12 \ln(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Find the exact length of the curve $y = \frac 12 x^2- \frac 12 \ln(x)$, for $2 \le x \le 4$.

My attempt:

\begin{align}
L&= \int_2^4 \sqrt{1+\left[x-\frac 1{2x} \right]^2} \, dx \\
&= \int_2^4 \sqrt{1+x^2+\frac 1{4x^2}-1} \, dx \\
&= \int_2^4 \sqrt{x^2+\frac 1{4x^2}} \, dx
\end{align}

But I am stuck here. How can I proceed from this step onwards?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible that there is a typo in the question: often in arclength problems, the constants are chosen so that $\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}$ miraculously turns out to be the square of something nice.  However, let us assume there is no typo.

We want to integrate $\frac{1}{2x}\sqrt{4x^4+1}$. Multiply top and bottom by $x^3$,  and make the change of variable $4x^4+1=u^2$. We arrive at a standard integral.

Comment: I was typing an answer to this by using completing square to remove the square root, unfortunately it didnt work out for me correctly in that way. Never thought of your way, how did you see this coming ? That we wanted to integrate $\frac{1}{2x}\sqrt{4x^4+1}$ , I mean how did you think of this? (Opz wanted to Upvote but Daily limit exceeded :p however obv you dont bother (being the king of math SE)!)

Comment: How does one think of "tricks"? Maybe it helps that I have taught calculus courses often, since I am OK with a huge class as long as the other course is upper level. Or perhaps because when I was young, and did not know any better, I did every integration problem in a calculus book.

Comment: Right, that explains.

Comment: @AndréNicolas What calculus book did you use?

Comment: Granville, Smith, and Longley. The teacher (who was really a Phys. Ed. teacher, and not good at math), had a copy. I had reasonable background knowledge, since elementary school was not in North America.

Comment: @AndréNicolas ,your awesome I would love to have a chat with you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known result which implies that there is a typo here. The result in question is, under some conditions, the arclength of a function f over [a,b] is given by an integral of the sqrt of a perfect squar if $f=F+G$ such that $F'*G'=(-1/4)$, for all $x$ in $[a,b]$. In this example we have $F'*G'=(-1/2)$. So a small variation of the data solve the typo problem. For example, we can take  $f(x)=-(1/8)x²+ln x$, or $f(x)=(1/4)x²-(1/2)ln(x)$, or $f(x)=x²-(1/8)ln x$. Among other possibilities.